# Удалились базы данных после улучшения Postgresql

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Собственно вопрос в теме. Улучшил Postgresql на Ubuntu 16.04 с 9.5 на 9.6. После улучшения пропали (стерлись) все базы данных, через \list показывает только template0 и template1. Возможно ли их как то восстановить или что делать в этой ситуации? Улучшал версию Postgresql по этому материалу https://gist.github.com/delameko/bd3aa2a54a15c50c723f0eef8f583a44

Comment: Развернуть из бэкапа и впредь аккуратнее делать миграцию кластера.

Comment: Получается миграция кластера стерла предыдущие базы вообще?

Comment: `pg_upgradecluster` переносит базы из кластера 9.5 в 9.6, а `pg_dropcluster` **удаляет** кластер 9.5 вместе со всем его содержимым.

Comment: то есть если дампа не было то восстановить уже не получится, так?

Comment: Да, так. Бэкапы быть должны, а особенно перед деструктивными операциями, типа обновлений СУБД.

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: ох, когда же пользователи дистрибутивов наконец поймут, что **не стоит** ставить пакеты из всяких **левых источников** (и сайт разработчиков какой-нибудь там программы **тоже** к ним относится)?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не до конца соглашусь. Если очень сильно надо + есть тестовый стенд + есть время на восстановление + есть автоматизация процесса деплоя и отката + есть бэкапы ровно до момента "да чё тут сложного, ща всё сделаем", то оно в принципе очень даже неплохо себя чувствует.